# SVN over http - PROPFIND 405

Tags: svn, apache-2.4, mod-dav-svn

I have a `Debian 8` server with `subversion` and `Apache 2.4.10` servers up and running.
I recently wanted to get subversion to work with `WebDav` due to the restrictive firewall of my company.

To get this whole thing working I use `mod_dav_svn` with `Basic` authentication and an `authz` access file.
The setup partly works, as I'm able to view the repository list in a browser and dig into the repositories (I can even view single files in the browser), therefore the permissions should be set up correctly.

I tried a whole load of different configuration options (it seems that many people encounter the `405 not allowed` problem).
For testing purposes I did not only use the `svn` client but also the `cadaver` client, which yielded the same `405` response.

This is the corresponding configuration my server uses, to see what I tried look at the bottom of this post as I made a list:

```
<Directory /svn>
    Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
    DirectoryIndex disabled
    Require all granted
    #DAV on
    #DavDepthInfinity on
</Directory>
<Location /svn/>
    Options -Indexes -ExecCGI -Includes -MultiViews +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine off
    DirectoryIndex disabled

    #Dav on
    #DavDepthInfinity on
    DAV svn
    SVNListParentPath on
    SVNParentPath /svn
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Subversion Repository"
    AuthUserFile /svn/passwd
    AuthzSVNAccessFile /svn/authz
    SSLRequireSSL

    <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
        Require valid-user
    </LimitExcept>
</Location>
```

Just to clarify:
I am able to pull and commit via `svn+ssh:`, the repositories are located under `/svn` where the group `svn` has the necessary permissions (the apache user is member of that group).
The `authz` file specifies read access for everyone - everywhere and write access to a specific group (I don't know if it's necessary to post it, due to it's minimal setup, please tell me if though).

List of things I tried (I don't have any links to the threads where this has been proposed, but almost everything is from google):

- setting `Location` to `/svn/` instead of `/svn`
- adding a `<Limit PROPFIND> require all granted </Limit>`
- setting `DavDepthInfinity on` as this is disabled by default
- adding a `<Directory /svn>`
- disabling index files for that directory and the location
- setting a `require all granted`
- setting `RewriteEngine off`

Well the things I've tried are random and as I said I took them from various threads around google.

I hope I pictured my problem well enough.
Any hint how this problem can be solved is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well this is kind of odd (at least in my eyes).
I previously tried to check out using this command:
`svn co https://my-domain.com/svn/repo`

This yielded the `405` response.
I just tried using this line:
`svn co https://www.my-domain.com/svn/repo`

And now it works like a charm.
It seems like this topic is of not much interest, but I would really appreciate someone giving me some insight in why the `www` is needed.